# How to verify pdf data in chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**How to verify data in PDF that opened in next tab in chrome. Can any body help on this.**

Comment: can u plz add a sample screen shot of the pdf content

Comment: The pdf is opened in next tab as soon as it clicked on the pdf link. Now, I should change the focus of selenium on the newly opened pdf browser and read the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the second tab like this:

```java
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

    if (!handle.equals(currentWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```